# How can I capture video from a webcam on Linux without worrying about the format?

Tags: linux, webcam, v4l2

I'm developing a Linux-only C++ app with a friend and I need to be able to capture a video feed from a specific USB device and then stream it. My biggest gripe currently is that every webcam seems to support different formats. I have two webcams that only support raw pixel formats but not the same ones, I have another webcam that supports raw pixel formats for lower resolutions but only compressed formats H264 and MJPEG for higher resolutions. I want to be able to capture from any webcam no matter what format it supports at the highest resolution it supports. I also want the frames to be at a constant format, it doesn't matter which one since I can convert it with libyuv but I420 would be preferable. How would I go about doing that?

I've only been able to capture a specific format using V4L2 directly (for example MJPG) but this is too low level.